# Where does the list-style-type : disc reflects when margin is set to 0px on li of a ul?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Consider the snippet:

```
            <ul id= "nav">
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> France</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Italy</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Spain</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Eastern Mediterranean</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "#"> Islands</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

[image]

The ***css*** in context:

```
#nav {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    margin: 10px;    // IF YOU SET IT TO 0, THEN THE CIRCULAR DISC DISSAPPEAR, WHY?
    border: 5px solid #FF0000
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `list-style-position` is `outside` hence if you dont specify a margin or padding the bullets would become hidden.

You can set the margin of `li` to be `0px` and the disc image would still appear if the `list-style-position` is `inside`.

```
ul li {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Read about [CSS list-style-position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp).

> The list-style-position property specifies if the list-item markers
>   should appear inside or outside the content flow.
>
> Default value:    **outside**

The image should help you understand better :

[image: List Style Property Explanation]

Here is the sample [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ukLq781/1/) with no `margin` and `list-style-position` set to `inside` and still the circular disc shows.

Comment: Happy to be of Help :)